# When I try to login through new user and try to update its balance it is giving me {"detail": "User not found", "code": "user_not_found"} this error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

My transaction API that I created where is this error occurring

My serializers

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'gender', 'age']


class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['account_id', 'account_no', 'balance']
```

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['account_id', 'transaction_type', 'transaction_balance']
```

My Views in Apps

```
# only use serializer here in request body and response
@swagger_auto_schema(method="post", request_body=LoginSerializer,
                     responses={"200": 'LoginSerializer'}, operation_id="user Login", )
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def login(request):
    # user can sign_in through this API
    serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        username = serializer.validated_data['username']
        password = serializer.validated_data['password']
        user_obj = User.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user_obj)
        return Response({'msg': 'Logged In', 'refresh': str(refresh), 'access': str(refresh.access_token)})
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```

```
@swagger_auto_schema(method="post", request_body=TransactionSerializer,
                     responses={"200": 'TransactionSerializer'}, operation_id="user signup transaction", )
@api_view(['POST'])
# @authentication_classes(JWTAuthentication)
# @permission_classes(IsAuthenticated)
def transaction(request):
    # all read and update of balance logic here from this API
    serializer = TransactionSerializer(data=request.data)
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    new_token = token.split(" ")
    decode_payload = jwt.decode(jwt=new_token[1], key=SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])
    user = decode_payload['user_id']
    if serializer.is_valid():
        user_id = user
        transaction_type = serializer.validated_data['transaction_type']
        acc_id = serializer.validated_data['account_id']
        tran_bal = serializer.validated_data['transaction_balance']
        if transaction_type == Transaction.TransactionType.DEPOSIT:
            acc_balance = Account.objects.get(id=acc_id.id, user_id=user_id)
            acc_balance.balance = acc_balance.balance + tran_bal
            acc_balance.save()
            # serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg': 'Account updated'})
        if transaction_type == Transaction.TransactionType.WITHDRAWAL:
            acc_balance = Account.objects.get(id=acc_id.id, user_id=user_id)
            acc_balance.balance = acc_balance.balance - tran_bal
            acc_balance.save()
            # serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg': 'Account updated'})
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```

In transaction I want to interact with the new row that i want to update my balance after logging in and generating new access token for the different user. I am stuck at while getting this error in my swagger API. Even after providing the bearer token and extracting the data from payload it is still giving me this error but when i try to login from the FIRST USER it working perfection and when i login to different user it gives me this. Please Help me fix my code

Comment: Can you please post the whole stack trace of the error that you are facing?

Comment: `user_obj = User.objects.get(username=username, password=password)` Does it even work ? You pass the password as received from the request but stored password in DB are hashed. So at first sight I'd say there is no user matching this query.

Comment: I created my own user model where it does not need hashed password I will edit my models also

Comment: @selflearnerprogrammer It is a really bad idea to store password as is in database. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Yup thank you but i was trying to make a project but i got the answer how to do it why was it showing me unauthorised

Answer (score 0):

Tacking this error will require you to create your own customised JWT authentication in different file in App

import jwt
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed, ParseError

from atm.settings import SECRET_KEY
from user.models import User

class JWTAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
def authenticate(self, request):
# Extract the JWT from the Authorization header
jwt_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
if jwt_token is None:
return None

```
    jwt_token = JWTAuthentication.get_the_token_from_header(jwt_token)  # clean the token
    # Decode the JWT and verify its signature

    # try:
    payload = jwt.decode(jwt_token, key=SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])
    # except jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError:
    #     raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid signature')
    # except:
    #     raise ParseError()

    # Get the user from the database
    # username_or_phone_number = payload.get('user_identifier')
    # if username_or_phone_number is None:
    #     raise AuthenticationFailed('User identifier not found in JWT')
    #
    # user = User.objects.filter(username=username_or_phone_number).first()
    # if user is None:
    #     user = User.objects.filter(phone_number=username_or_phone_number).first()
    #     if user is None:
    #         raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found')

    username = payload.get('user_id')
    if username is None:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('User identifier not found in JWT')

    user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    if user is None:
        user = User.objects.filter(phone_number=username)
        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found')

    # Return the user and token payload
    print(user, payload)
    return user, payload

@classmethod
def get_the_token_from_header(cls, token):
    token = token.replace('Bearer', '').replace(' ', '')  # clean the token
    return token
```

then add this file in main settings.py file as

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ['user.custom_authentication.JWTAuthentication'],
}